# Is there a way to overwrite existing data using pandas to_parquet with partitions?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I'm using pandas to write a parquet file using the to_parquet function with partitions. Example:

```
df.to_parquet('gs://bucket/path', partition_cols=['key'])
```

The issue is that every time I run the code. It adds a new parquet file in the partition and when you read data, you get all the data from each time the script was run. Essentially, the data appends each time.

Is there a way to overwrite the data every time you write using pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there is. You need to read pandas docs and you'll see that to_parquet supports **kwargs and uses engine:pyarrow by default. With that you got to the pyarrow docs. There you'll see there are two methods of doing this. One, by using partition_filename_cb which needs legacy support and will be depricated.
Two, using basename_template which is the new way. This because of performance issues of running a callable/lambda to name each partition. You need to pass a string: `"string_{i}"`. Only works with legacy support off. The saved file will be "string_0","string_1"...
You can't use both at the same time.

```
def write_data(
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    path: str,
    file_format="csv",
    comp_zip="snappy",
    index=False,
    partition_cols: list[str] = None,
    basename_template: str = None,
    storage_options: dict = None,
    **kwargs,
) -> None:
    getattr(pd.DataFrame, f"to_{file_format}")(
        df,
        f"{path}.{file_format}",
        compression=comp_zip,
        index=index,
        partition_cols=partition_cols,
        basename_template=basename_template,
        storage_options={"token": creds},
        **kwargs,
    )
```

Try this.

Comment: How do you turn legacy support off? I have pyarrow 6 and this should work but it doesn't (TypeError: unexpected keyword argument)

Answer (score 1):

Use `existing_data_behavior` with `delete_matching`. E.g.:

```py
df.to_parquet(
    'gs://bucket/path', 
    partition_cols=['key'], 
    existing_data_behavior='delete_matching'
)
```

From [pyarrow docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset.html):

> ‘delete_matching’ is useful when you are writing a partitioned dataset. The first time each partition directory is encountered the entire directory will be deleted. This allows you to overwrite old partitions completely.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [dask](/questions/tagged/dask) to be helpful reading and writing parquet. It defaults the file name on write (which you can alter) and will replace the parquet file if you use the same name, which I believe is what you are looking for. You can append data to the partition by setting 'append' to True, which is more intuitive to me, or you can set 'overwrite' to True which will remove all files in the partition/folder prior to writing the file. Reading parquet works well as well by including partition columns in the dataframe on read.

https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.to_parquet.html

See below some code I used to satisfy myself of the behaviour of dask.dataframe.to_parquet:

```
import pandas as pd
from dask import dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range("2015-01-01", "2022-06-30")
df_len = len(dates)
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(df_len, 1)), columns=["value"])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(df_len, 1)), columns=["value"])

df_1["date"] = dates
df_1["YEAR"] = df_1["date"].dt.year
df_1["MONTH"] = df_1["date"].dt.month

df_2["date"] = dates
df_2["YEAR"] = df_2["date"].dt.year
df_2["MONTH"] = df_2["date"].dt.month

ddf_1 = dd.from_pandas(df_1, npartitions=1)
ddf_2 = dd.from_pandas(df_2, npartitions=1)

name_function = lambda x: f"monthly_data_{x}.parquet"

ddf_1.to_parquet(
    "dask_test_folder",
    name_function=name_function,
    partition_on=["YEAR", "MONTH"],
    write_index=False,
)

print(ddf_1.head())
ddf_first_write = dd.read_parquet("dask_test_folder/YEAR=2015/MONTH=1")
print(ddf_first_write.head())

ddf_2.to_parquet(
    "dask_test_folder",
    name_function=name_function,
    partition_on=["YEAR", "MONTH"],
    write_index=False,
)

print(ddf_2.head())
ddf_second_write = dd.read_parquet("dask_test_folder/YEAR=2015/MONTH=1")
print(ddf_second_write.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you use, an older version and you need to use the parameter `partition_filename_cb`, this is the usage:

```
df.to_parquet('gs://bucket/path', partition_cols=['key'], partition_filename_cb="constant_{}".format)
```

You need to pass the format function so it's a callable that returns the filename string given a key.